# An extra line while using STROKE as style using Canvas

Tags: android, canvas, styles, fill, stroke

I'm trying to draw a 2D Triangle in Android studio using canvas, So if I'm using the below code for drawing a triangle without filling it, It is giving an extra line. 
While If I'm using the same code for filling the triangle, the output is proper.
Below is my code for both the cases:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new MyView (MainActivity.this));
    }

    public class MyView extends View{
        public MyView(Context context){
            super(context);
        }

        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            Paint paint=new Paint();
            Path path=new Path();
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            canvas.drawPaint(paint);
            Point a=new Point(300,200);
            Point b=new Point(100,500);
            Point c=new Point(900,800);

            paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);

            path.lineTo(a.x,a.y);
            path.lineTo(b.x,b.y);
            path.lineTo(c.x,c.y);
            path.lineTo(a.x,a.y);
            path.close();
            canvas.drawPath(path,paint);}
```

With Stroke style:
[image]

With Fill style: [image]

Answer (score 0):

Use first:

```
path.moveTo()
```

then

```
path.lineTo()
path.lineTo()
path.lineTo()
```